# AJAX Data insertion on load

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am trying to insert data into database using php but i don't know how to do this in fact i have search google as well but no proper solution.

My Ajax code is:

```
if(window.location == "path/to/file") {
    $(window).on('load',function() {
        var id = $("#id").val();
        var cd = $("#cd").val();
        var ed = $("#ed").val();
        var status = $("#status").val();

        if(ed == cd){
            status = "Stopped";
            console.log(status);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "wba.php",
                data: "status=" + status,
                success: function(data) {
                   alert("sucess");
                }
            });
        }
        else{
            console.log('Running');
        }
    });
}
```

Now i don't know that how to get data from ajax and insert it into my db using php and my DB table structure is

```
INSERT into table_name(id, cd, ed, status) VALUES();
```

My WBA.php File Code is mentioned below in this file i am getting data from table first and then when the current time become equals to ending time i want this page to automatically change status of ad from running to stopped and update value in database without refreshing page and without even clicking on any button.

```
<div id="main-content">
<div class="casteform">
<?php
    $query = "SELECT * FROM advertisements WHERE ad_category = 'weddingbellsad'";
    $run = mysqli_query($con, $query);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($run) > 0){
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run)) {
            $ad_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $row['ad_id']);
            $ad_company = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $row['ad_company']);
            $ad_start_date = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $row['ad_start_date']);
            $ad_duration = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $row['ad_duration']);
            $ad_reminder_days = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $row['ad_reminder_days']);
            $ad_reminder_date = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $row['ad_reminder_date']);
            $ad_end_date = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $row['ad_end_date']);
            $ad_payment_method = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $row['ad_payment_method']);
            $ad_payment_amount = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $row['ad_payment_amount']);
            $ad_category = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $row['ad_category']);
            $ad_status = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $row['ad_status']);
            $ad_current_date = date('Y-m-d h:i:s');
        ?>
            <div class="adrow">
                <h4>Company Name: <?php echo $ad_company . " ( " . $ad_id . " ) "; ?> <small><?php echo $ad_status ?></small></h4>
                <ul>
                    <li><span>Starting Date:</span> <?php echo $ad_start_date; ?></li>
                    <li><span>Duration:</span> <?php echo $ad_duration . " Days"; ?></li>
                    <li><span>Reminder:</span> <?php echo "Before ". $ad_reminder_days . " Day(s)"; ?></li>
                    <li><span>Reminder Date:</span> <?php echo $ad_reminder_date; ?></li>
                    <li><span>Ending Date:</span> <?php echo $ad_end_date; ?></li>
                    <li><span>Payment Method:</span> <?php echo $ad_payment_method; ?></li>
                    <li><span>Payment Amount:</span> <?php echo "Rs - " . $ad_payment_amount; ?></li>
                    <li><span>Ad Category:</span> <?php echo $ad_category; ?></li>
                </ul>
                <form>
                    <input type="text" id="id" value="<?php echo $ad_id; ?>" />
                    <input type="text" id="cd" value="<?php echo $ad_current_date; ?>" />
                    <input type="text" id="ed" value="<?php echo $ad_end_date; ?>" />
                    <input type="text" id="status" value="<?php echo $ad_status; ?>" />
                </form>
            </div>
        <?php
        }
    }
    else{
        header("location: view-wedding-bell-ad.php?error=".urlencode("No advertisements found so far."));
        exit();
    }
?>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is your wba.php file? Share us that too

Comment: the only var you are passing through ajax is status. So in your php you can only get status this way... $_POST['status']

Comment: @MdMonjurUlHasan I have added WBA File code as well. please check

Comment: @Roy i am not able to understand your point can you please explain a bit because for last 3 hours i am stuck in this problem

Comment: Check @IncredibleHat answer

Answer (score 1):

To pass multiple values through ajax, you'll need to adjust your `.ajax` call as such (note the `data` change):

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "wba.php",
    data: {
        "id" : id,
        "cd" : cd,
        "ed" : ed,
        "status" : status
    },
    success: function(data) {
        alert("sucess");
    }
});
```

And then on PHP's side in your **wba.php** you get at those values with:

```
$_POST['id']
$_POST['cd']
$_POST['ed']
$_POST['status']
```

As for all the other database interaction and such, we would need you to make an attempt at that yourself, and figure out your goals and needed results. Its a bit broad and out of scope for StackOverflow for someone else to write all of that for you at this point. You can always ask another question to cover specific walls you run into if you need further help.

HOWEVER IMPORTANTLY: be sure you utilize "Prepared Statements" ! As that will help protect you from one of the most common attack vectors.

An example starter (http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php):

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT into table_name(id, cd, ed, status) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param('ssss', $_POST['id'], $_POST['cd'], $_POST['ed'], $_POST['status']);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: I have tried to update database table field value of staus but it not working, here is my code

$id = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['id']);
$status = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['status']);
$upq = "UPDATE advertisements SET ad_status = '$status' WHERE ad_id = '$id'";
$rupq = mysqli_query($con, $query);


besides this it is also giving me error that is listed below:

Notice: Undefined index: id in path\wba.php on line 62

Notice: Undefined index: status in path\wba.php on line 63

Comment: Sounds like the POST vars are not being sent at the time you are defining those variables. If you are doing that on first load of wba.php, then they won't exist. You would need to only do that if it came from ajax. So check for existence like `if ( isset($_POST['id']) ) { ... }` before doing the SQL.

Comment: Ajax id, status is showing proper result in console.log() but not updating database record can you please help me out in this. here is the code

if(isset($_POST['id'])){
echo $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['id']);
echo $status = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['status']);
$upq = "UPDATE advertisements SET ad_status = '$status' WHERE ad_id = '$id'";
$rupq = mysqli_query($con, $upq);
}